# Looking for a way to make a loop that rejects an input with any other hour format other than the one specified

Tags: c, while-loop

Im having trouble creating a code on C that after letting the user input an hour it determines if the hour is in a valid 24 hour format and written as HH:MM, in the case it isn't it loops back and lets him input the hour indefinitely until it is a possible hour, any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool format_correct(char format[]);
int looper;
char hour[] = "11:11";

int main()
{
while (looper == 1);{

printf("insert time in format HH:MM\n");
scanf("%s", &hour);
  
  if ((hour < 25) && format_correct(hour)){
    printf("%s is a correct hour",hour);
    looper ++;
    }
  else   
    printf("incorrect format, introduce time in format HH:MM \n");
   
    
  return 0;
  }  
}

bool format_correct(char format[])
{
  if (strlen(format) != 5) return false;
  if (!isdigit(format[0])) return false;
  if (!isdigit(format[1])) return false;
  if (format[2] != ":") return false;
  if (!isdigit(format[3])) return false;
  if (!isdigit(format[4])) return false;


}
```

Comment: `if ((hour < 25)` ?? You can not compare strings and numbers in this way, check [strtol](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol), you should also protect `scanf` from buffer overflows and check the result  `if (scanf("%5s", &hour) == 1) {...} else { /* bad input */ }`

Comment: okok, thanks for the link and the response! i don't understand what the second part of the comment means tho, you mean i need to flush the memory?

Comment: If user input is unreliable, don't even use `scanf`. Input with `fgets()` into a string that is longer than you are expecting, for example `char input[42];` to lessen the chance that you can't take the whole input. Use `sscanf` etc to check the content. If incorrect, repeat the loop.

Comment: You don't need to flush the memory, your array is limited to 6 characters including the trailing 0,  if the user enter more than 5 characters you overflow the buffer (and probably get a segfault), with `%5s` you tell `scanf` to scan at most 5 characters.

Comment: `if (format[2] != ":")` is also wrong, you compare characters with single quotes: `if (format[2] != ':')`, and `while (looper == 1);{` is very suspicious ... and another minor issue: `hour` decays into a pointer when is passed to a function, you can remove the `&` in `scanf("%s", &hour);`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.